# Subresource integrity for ES6 module import

Tags: javascript, cdn, es6-modules, subresource-integrity

Considering one may want to import JS modules from CDNs or so, it may be important to ensure the integrity of the delivered JS modules.

Fortunately, in the "old" integration method, we already had solved that problem with [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity).

However, I see no way this is anywhere possible [when importing ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

So is there any way or any plan to implement this thing?

Comment: Can't you make a `<script type="module" integrity="…" …>` for each of your (recursive) dependencies?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but then you loose all advantages of ES6 modules. :)